# Kotlin not receiving a full packet from an HC-06 Bluetooth module

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I am having an issue with data not fully loading into the buffer in Android in one packet. I am sending <7:16> data packet from a HC-06 bluetooth module.
When i receive it's coming in as 2 packets. The micro is sending a CR and LF and the end of the transmission.

```
I/UI_Msg: <  
I/UI_Msg: 7:16>  
I/UI_Msg: <  
I/UI_Msg: 7:16>  
etc
```

If I add a sleep command for a second, then query the buffer it comes in completed in one packet.  The problem is I want to send more than one packet in a second..

How can i fix this issue to or can i just build a string until '>' is received from the buffer.

```
private fun beginListenForData() {
  val handler = Handler()
    stopThread = false
    buffer = ByteArray(10)
    val thread = Thread(Runnable {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted && !stopThread) {
            try {
                val byteCount = inputStream!!.available()
                if (byteCount > 0) {
                    //Thread.sleep(1000)      // wait for buffer finish filling
                    val rawBytes = ByteArray(byteCount)
                    inputStream!!.read(rawBytes)
                    val string = String(rawBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    //handler.post {txt_message.text=""}
                    Log.i(TAG,""+ string)
                    //handler.post {txt_message.append(string)}
                   // processInput(string)
                }
            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                stopThread = true
            }
        }

    })

    thread.start()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figgured it out. Read the buffer one byte at a time and build the string character at a time. Check for the < and the > character for a valid transmission

```
private fun beginListenForData() {

stopThread = false
val thread = Thread(Runnable {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted && !stopThread) {
        try {
            val byteCount = inputStream!!.available()
            if (byteCount > 0) {
                val rawBytes = ByteArray(1)
                inputStream!!.read(rawBytes,0,1)
                val string = String(rawBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                if (string== "<") {
                    m_Headder=true
                }
                if (m_Headder==true){
                    stringBuilder = stringBuilder.plus(string)
                    if (string ==">") {
                        m_Received=stringBuilder
                        Log.i(TAG, "string:" + stringBuilder)
                        stringBuilder = ""
                        m_Headder = false
                        ProcessMessage(m_Received)
                   }
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            stopThread = true
        }
    }

})
thread.start()

}
```